# Variable gets passed to pushed ViewController when declaring outside

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have simple example:

1. NavViewController
2. ViewController
3. ViewController2

In ViewController:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

NSArray *array;// Neither in @interface nor in @implementation 

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"12345", nil];

    ViewController2 *vc = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

In ViewConroller2:

```
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()

@end

NSArray *array;

@implementation ViewController2

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"%@",array);


}
```

I don't understand why my array in viewController2 **passed data** from viewController?
Can explain this?

**Guys I know how pass data to another viewController with property. I want to understand why, in this case, the data is transferred!**

Comment: What does the NSLog print?

Comment: NSLog print 2014-08-26 16:29:56.781 example[6034:60b] (
    12345
)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: It shouldn't, and probably didn't. Add another NSLog with self in view controller 2.

Comment: I know it shouldn't. But that data is passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare your variable outside `@interface or @implementation` it is considered to be `static variable` hence it worked. keep it inside would not work.

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
 NSArray *array;
}
@end
```

try this instead of your code

Comment: iDev, can u show explanation/manuals about statics variable, because I don't use static variables in my projects, and encountered for the first time

Comment: By printing the description you would be able to get. Because both the class array description is same

Answer (score 1):

Because you've declared `NSArray *array;` as a Global variable. And, as long as the variable is defined somewhere in a source file, the linker will be able to find it and appropriately link all the references in other source files to the definition.

we also declare global variables using `extern`

```
extern int GlobalVar;
```

Here, `extern`tells the compiler that this is just a declaration that an object of type int identified by GlobalVar exists and linker's job to ensure.

In one of your source file, you could say

```
int GlobalVar = 7;
```

I believe this is the reason in your case.